# Linux Kernel defines everywhere

Tags: c, linux-kernel

On linux's kernel we can find this piece of code in `linux/sched.h`, when I saw it some doubts came to my mind:

1. Why using define to create functions? Why not using the normal `return-type function-name(par1, par2) {}` style?
2. What is the point with the `do {} while(0)`?

   ```
   #define set_special_state(state_value)  
       do {  
           unsigned long flags;  
           raw_spin_lock_irqsave(&current->pi_lock, flags);  
           current->state = (state_value);  
           raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore(&current->pi_lock, flags);  
       } while (0)  
   #endif
   ```

Comment: 1. Portability. Some function need flags that are different on different architectures and/or compilers and/or those flags changed with kernel versions. So people doesn't have to change the function declaration each time some guy changes kernel section naming, those are wrapped in macros. 2. Search google for `do while C macro`, it is a common, standard practice to warp multiline macro statements in `do{}while(0)`. Thers even MISRA-C:2004 rule 19.4

Comment: @KamilCuk Does `({})` and `do{}while(0)` have any difference? I've tried both of them, and found that they're interchangeable. Do I missed anything crucial? Thanks!

Comment: `({})` makes no sense in C, except it's a GNU compiler extension. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html#Swallowing-the-Semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a "function", it's a preprocessor macro.

1. Sometimes one must use macros to do things that the C language itself doesn't support  (usually generating code). This doesn't look like one of those cases though, and should probably be a `static inline` function. Pergaps the Git history would explain why it is the way it is.
2. `do { ... } while (0)` is a common method for swallowing the semicolon which follows a call to a C-function-looking macro like this one.

Comment: It *might* need to be a macro: one possibility is that is has to support `state_value` being a function call instead of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are usually preferrable because they provide type checking and aren't error prone to things like double evaluation, but macros are more powerful, since they allow you to work at the text/token level.

`do{}while(0)` is to make an invoked macro grammatically behave like a void-returning function call.

You might think a plain pair of curlies would do that but that doesn't work
with if-else

```
#define macro_with_curlies() { }
if(x) macro_with_curlies(); else { }
//expands to: if(x) { }; /*else is illegal after the semicolon*/ else { }
```